# There is no way to create a reference to stream & it’s not possible to reuse the same stream multiple times

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Reading article about java 8 stream, and found

> Java Streams are consumable, so there is no way to create a reference
>   to stream for future usage. Since the data is on-demand, it’s not
>   possible to reuse the same stream multiple times.

at the same time at the same article

```
//sequential stream
Stream<Integer> sequentialStream = myList.stream();

//parallel stream
Stream<Integer> parallelStream = myList.parallelStream();
```

What does it mean of "there is no way to create a reference to stream for future usage" ? aren't `sequentialStream` and `parallelStream` references to streams

also what does it mean of "it’s not possible to reuse the same stream multiple times" ?

Comment: The article is wrong to say *there is no way to create a reference to stream for future usage*: You *can* create a reference for future use. The variables in your question are examples. Those references could be passed to an asynchronous consumer for example and so would be consumed well into the future. Even operating on your stream variables a few lines later in the method is still “future usage”, because it happens at a time after the reference is obtained.

Comment: The important phrase is the last one “*it’s not possible to reuse the same stream multiple times*”. Read the rest under that premise.

Answer (score 5):

What it means is that every time you need to operate on a stream, you must make a new one.

So you cannot, for example, have something like:

```
Class Person {
    private Stream<String> phoneNumbers;

    Stream<String> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }
}
```

and just reuse that one stream whenever you like.  Instead, you must have something like

```
Class Person {
    private List<String> phoneNumbers;

    Stream<String> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers.stream();  // make a NEW stream over the same data
    }
}
```

The code snipped you included does just that.  It makes 2 different streams over the same data